# MySQL: Show record from specif id

Tags: php, mysql

you can view the records in my database from a certain value on?

I have to make implementation of this query :

```
$ query_dati_lista = " SELECT * FROM AM_Ordini id_matrimonio WHERE IS NOT NULL ORDER BY cod_ordine DESC" ;
```

Within the database there are many records , but I do not need everyone.

it's possible?

[image: my_image]

Comment: Please add your table structure, example data and expected output.

Comment: *WHERE IS NOT NULL* ? What are you trying to do?

Comment: what is your WHERE condition exactly.  display your table structure

Comment: [link]http://s28.postimg.org/etbw0qnpp/Schermata_2015_06_11_alle_14_59_00.png

Comment: Then which records you need

Comment: Show record from id= 1714 but id_matrimonio field must not be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you're not specifying what columns to search in for your `WHERE` clause:

```
$query_dati_lista = "
SELECT *
FROM AM_Ordini
WHERE `id_matrimonio` IS NOT NULL AND `id` = 1714
ORDER BY cod_ordine DESC";
```

Let's break down this query:

- `SELECT *` means, I want to grab every field from the tables I'm searching for
- `FROM AM_Ordini`, this is the table I'm searching in
- `` WHERE `id_matrimonio` IS NOT NULL AND `id` = 1714 ``, this is your search conditions. You're saying, I want rows where `id_matrimonio` is NOT NULL, and where `id` is 1714. You can add multiple and/or, and group using paracentesis.
- `ORDER BY cod_ordine DESC` tells you that you want things in order from greatest to least by the field cod_ordine. Be aware, if you're intent is to search for one row (Like `id` 1714), then this is pretty much useless.

Comment: in this way , I see only one result .

I have to see the results from 1714 .

There are many records after that.

Comment: Then do ``WHERE `id_matrimonio` IS NOT NULL AND `id` >= 1714``. It will select records starting at 1714.

Comment: ok, perfect. I mistyped the query , but it was correct .

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a specific record your WHERE statement needs to be specified.  When stating WHERE IS NOT NULL, your not specifying a COLUMN in your table on what should not be null.

Specific queries can be like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id='1';
```

The 'table_name' is the name you specified for the database table.  'id' is a specific column on your table that you want to check against.  When retrieving specific row in your database table you have no need to order by.

If you have a query that has the same value for multiple records such as;

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE price IS NOT NULL;
```

... then you can order by like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE price IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC;
```

In the example above 'price' is the name of a specific column on your database table.  IS NOT NULL is a way of retrieving fields that are empty in that particular row.

Hope this helps.   Please try to be more specific to get an answer to match your requirement.